# Peer to Peer Connection in IOS swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I need help with this code. I followed a tutorial from 2014 and I have an error with dispatch_async. I am trying to create an app that allows the user to play with other player nearby or peer to peer. I think the code needs to be updated because it has been renamed in swift 4 but I don't know what the new name is.

This is the code

```
// below is where the code are wrong
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MPC_DidChangeStateNotification",object:nil,userInfo: userInfo)
        })
```

the full code is in this link  https://github.com/javaplanet17/test/blob/master/multipeer it is inside of a func on line 36.

the error list 
first I got this error

```
MPCHandler.swift:55:9: 'NSNotificationCenter' has been renamed to 'NotificationCenter'
```

I pressed fix and renamed it then I got another error

```
MPCHandler.swift:55:123: Use of unresolved identifier 'userInfo'
```

I pressed fix and renamed it then I still got an error

```
MPCHandler.swift:55:45: Cannot call value of non-function type 'NotificationCenter' Replace '()' with ''
```

Once again I pressed fix and changed it

The code now look like this:

```
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotificationName("MPC_DidChangeStateNotification",object:nil,userInfo: userinfo)
```

Then I updated it to:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ () -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post("MPC_DidChangeStateNotification",object:nil,userInfo: userinfo)
        })
```

yet I still got an error

```
MPCHandler.swift:55:121: Extra argument 'userInfo' in call
```

I have tried to change it into:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:{ () -> Void in NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userinfo))
        })
```

but I still get an error. How do I fix this error?

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the complete and exact error.

Comment: You have an extra `)`.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me this way might try it out

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { _ in
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
})
```

Comment: here is all of the function

Comment: func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        let userInfo = ["peerID":peerID, "state":state.rawValue] as [String : Any]
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        })

Comment: Please use [edit] instead of adding the information in comments.